# asp.net 'server error in '/' application' message with all aspx files in site

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm seeing the  "Server Error in '/' Application." message on a number of sites on my server. These sites can be as simple as an empty IIS site containing an index.aspx file with no ASP code, indicating there may be some sort of configuration issue.

I can't find any more about the error, as changing the web.config file to allow me to view these errors doesn't work, and the site isn't available from localhost, so I can't see a more detailed error so I'm wondering if it's some sort of configuration issue.

aspx files seem to be working fine on the default site on this server, and on one of the other sites, but not on some of the others or any new ones I create.

Does anyone have any idea how I can troubleshoot this issue further?

**Edited to provide my index.aspx file and web.config file**

index.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>ASPX Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ASPX Test
    </body>
</html>
```

web.config

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you looked in the application log of the server that has IIS on it? it's usually a good dumping ground for that information.

Comment: @OnResolve I've taken a look at the application log ans there aren't any relevent entries relating to IIS or .net

Answer (score 4):

There are three main possibilities:

1. Within IIS, your sites are not configured to use the correct ASP.Net runtime.  This would result in the site being unable to properly read a web.config file or, flat not executing any .Net files like .aspx.
2. Your .Net installation is corrupted/incomplete and needs to be reinstalled.
3. The format of your web.config files don't match the .Net runtime version.

Start with the first one by looking to ensure that the sites have the proper runtime selected in your app pools.

---

From a comment you left on another question, this came to mind.

I'm not sure why you are trying to create a .net 1.1 site, but the absolute minimum you need in your web.config is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815179

If you are trying to turn off custom errors (thereby displaying ALL error info to the client) then it should be in the system.web section.  For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Can you let me know how I'd check number 1? The working and none working sites all have the same information for application name, execute permissions, application pool and asp.net version

Comment: I thought the same as Chris, but if you are saying  some sites work, then check if your aspx files are correct and your web.config is not corrupted. Some times times an error in @Page directive causes application errors

Comment: I've posted my index.html and web.config files in my original post - the web.config file is almost identical to yours (I don't have an explict end tag on the customErrors tag). I have tried these two files (and only these files) in the root of one site and they work and the root of another and they don't. As you can see I don't have an @Page directive so I wonder if this relates to somesort of configuration issue with all aspx files for a site

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find any more about the error, as changing the web.config file
>   to allow me to view these errors doesn't work

This is not true. You can enable detailed error information for remote computers (although **NOT** recommended to leave it on) by setting this on your Web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
</customErrors>
```

Also, set the `debug="true"` in the compilation section of your `web.config` to get more detailed information.

[More details here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)

Comment: Hi Icarus, can you let me know how I get this to work. I've created a new IIS site with just an index.aspx and a web.config. The web.config contains only the customErrors tag and it doesn't seem to have any effect/

Answer (score 0):

Long shot, but are the sites set to the correct .NET version?

Comment: All sites are set to version 1.1.4322

Comment: and the sites that don't work, are they created in .Net 1.1 or .net 2+?

Comment: Are you referring to the code? I'm currently just testing with a html file with a .aspx and am seeing the issue, so I don't think it relates to the actual contents of the sites at all, just the processing of any aspx file.

Comment: yeah, i was refering to the aspx pages and .net websites. i've had a similar thing when i've created a .net2 site before and it turned out that the  website was trying to interpret it as a .net 1.1 site. So in the same way if (accidentally) you code a website in .net2 but need it to be .net1.1 it'll bug out. I would imagine checking the <assemblies> section in the web.config and seeing if you have the right framework versions of dlls for the website (i.e. not anything "Version=2.0.0.0")

Comment: As per the edit to my question, there's nothing specific to a particular .net version in my code but I guess it may still be a version issue somehow

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, surely a base aspx file should look like

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

or like this if using code behind

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

your updated question implies that IIS is trying to process/interpret a standard HTML file as a ASPX file, which surely won't work as it requires some specific elements (runat="server")

Comment: As far as I'm aware an aspx file doesn't need to contain any asp code or even a @page directive - please let me know if this is incorrect? To simplify the issue I've stripped all code out of the file - it processes fine on one of the IIS sites, but fails with an error on the other.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem twice as i remember:

First one when i added a virtual directory that pointed at a folder where my website exists. It was solved by "Convert to Application", done by right clicking on my virtual directory icon (in the left navigation pane) then selecting "Convert to Application".

Second one was because wrong configuration of my application pool. It was resolved by changing the application pool of my application to another well configured one.